# How to get a especif class after other especific class in python with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In the website source i found this:

```
 <div class = "g">..<\div>
 <div class = "g">..<\div>
 <div class = "g">..<\div>
 <div class = "g">..<\div>
 <jsmodel="gpo5Gf" class="LnbJhc"...>..<\div>
 <div class = "g">..<\div>
 <div class = "g">..<\div>
```

I need to acces/get the information of the class `"g"`, but **only** those that are after the `jsmodel`

Can someone help me?

I'm using python3/beautifulsoup

Comment: did you read documentation for `beautifulsoup` ? `beautifulsoup` has any usefull function and it is good to know them (even if you don't use them every day).

Comment: yeah, i have read the documentation and tried to implement the "find_next"/"find_next_all" but i failed

Comment: then you should say it in question. And if you get error message then you should show it in question. This way we don't have to waste time for things which you already know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you mean `<div jsmodel="..."` instead of `<jsmodel="..."`

---

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) has many functions - not only `find()` and `find_all()`.

There is also `find_next()`, `find_all_next()`, `find_next_sibling()`, `find_next_siblings()`, etc.

So you can use `find()` to  `div` with `jsmodel` and later use `find_next()` to search next element.

```
text = '''
<div class="g">..</div>
<div class="g">..</div>
<div jsmodel="gpo5Gf" class="LnbJhc">..</div>
<div class="g">FIRST</div>
<div class="g">SECOND</div>
<div class="x">OTHER class</div>
'''
 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

model = soup.find('div', {'jsmodel': True})
#model = soup.find('div', {'jsmodel': "gpo5Gf"})

div = model.find_next('div')
#div = model.find_next('div', {'class', 'g'})

print(div)
```

Comment: so you can mark my answer as accepted. And after few minutes you can upvote it.

Comment: I use this answer to creat post also with `find_previous()` [Python: How to find element next after another element with BeautifulSoup.](https://blog.furas.pl/python-how-to-to-fine-element-next-after-another-element-with-beautifulsoup-gb.html)